# How to manage escape sequences?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm trying to write a protocol as much simple as possible to make two processes talk through a socket. I'd like to separate control commands from raw data. How can I get this? I mean, if sockets carry only a bytes stream, how can my protocol, for example, distinguish the escape sequence "ESC STX" from the numbers sequence 2734? I've searched a bit, but not enough I suppose, since I've not yet found how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at protocol buffers, or other encoding scheme -- also look on wikipedia for length encoded values and similar encoding

Comment: Just add the control command "Now I will send data with length X" followed by the X byte long data.

Comment: That's why escape sequences are _"escaped"_ as they appear in the payload (usually using a 0x25).

Comment: It mainly depends on whether or not the receiver already knows the type he receives. If he does, you don't need to escape. If he doesn't, you either should escape such "special" symbols in "normal" data, or you prepend the data with a type-symbol to get the former case (e.g. prepend integers with an "i", strings with "s" etc. and when reading, the char tells you which parse-function to call).

Answer (score 4):

Establish a message *protocol*.

For example:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+  
| Command | Payload   | Checksum |  
| 2 bytes | 252 bytes | 2 bytes  |  
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

The payload can contain any pattern because the payload is fixed size.

For variable length message, the message length should be added:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------+  
| Command | Message Length | Payload   | Checksum |  
| 2 bytes |    2 bytes     | ? bytes   | 2 bytes  |  
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

The length of the payload is determined by the size of the Message Length field.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest solution might be to open 2 connections.**

One Port/Connection is for control-commands (metadata), and the other Connection is for data.

**If 2 connections are not an option, you could split you data into "messages".**

Each message contains a message-head and a message-body. The message-head contains the following fields:

- Message-Body length (=number of bytes of the body. needed to identify the beginning of the next message)
- Message-Type (To distinguish between escape-sequences like `ESC STX` and actual data)

Due to the reason that the length of the message-head is known, the receiver always knows what type of data is receives. 
However you should also add some kind of checksum-field in the header.

**Escaping**

Just define a special byte (eg. `0x00`) to be an escape-character. Everytime you want to transmit escape-sequences (`ESC STX`), you send this byte before.

However, if you want to send the data `0x00`, you have to send it twice. The receiver then has to to some replacing:

- `0x00` followed by `0x00` --> no escape sequences. Remove one byte, and everything is ok
- `0x00` followed by any other byte --> remove the `0x00`-byte. The second byte is an escape-sequence and has a special meaning.